I have a problem about Ethereum transaction listening and logs
ethereum node websockets have logs for tokens and nft's, more precisely contracts, and by subscribing to these logs, you can directly listen to specific addresses according to the values you want.
However, in order to listen to ETH transfers, you need to listen to all transactions. And to find a specific address, you need to request the RPC endpoint each time with getTransaction and compare.
Assuming we are using private RPC, there are hundreds of requests per second.
Is there any way to avoid this? I mean, can't I subscribe directly to a specific address like in the logs and catch the transactions?
